# Plato's forms - sparse realism and scope of forms

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, plato, properties, universals

Was Plato a sparse realist about universals? (because "Carve nature at its joints")

And did he think everyday human made objects and social kinds had forms? eg tables

Thanks